# How to ignore (and not omit) missing values within a function in R?

Tags: r

I have three functions shown below (`rulefour`, `rulefive`, and `ruleone`).

However, `cl, ucl, and lcl` (defined in all three functions) all contain some missing values.  I assume I would have to use `na.rm=TRUE` in each function, but I am not sure where I would include it. Please advise, thank you! Currently when I run the code, R just omits the rows. I am wanting it to ignore the NA values and not omit any rows.

```
 rulefour <- function(values,cl){
        cl <- as.numeric(as.character(cl))
        len <- length(values)
        We4 <- matrix(nrow = 1,ncol = 1) #initialize Rule 4 matrix
        if (is.numeric(cl)){
            cntsabove <- values>cl #check if value is above or below
            cntsbelow <- values<cl
            for (i in 8:len){
                indx <- i-7
                temp <- cntsabove[i:indx]  #check for sequential logical results by increments of 8
                temp2 <- cntsbelow[i:indx]
                if (all(temp == TRUE)){     #if at least 8 sequential, keep index of value
                    val <- i:indx
                    We4 <- append(We4,val) 
                    
                }
                else if (all(temp2 == TRUE)){
                    val <- i:indx
                    We4 <- append(We4,val)
                }
            }  
        }
        We4 <- We4[!duplicated(We4)] #clean up data
        We4 <- We4[!is.na(We4)]
        We4 <- sort(We4)
        return(We4)
    }
    
rulefive <- function(values){
    len <- length(values)
    temp <- rep(0,len)       #initialize temp, temp2, and We5 array
    temp2 <- rep(0,len)
    We5 <- rep(0,len)
    for (i in 2:len){
        if (values[i]>values[i-1]){ #create logical confirming increase
            temp[i] <- 1
        }
        if (values[i]<values[i-1]){  #create logical confirming increase
            temp2[i] <- 1
        }
    }
    
    v1 <- sequence(rle(temp)$lengths) * temp  #check for sequential increase
    v2 <- sequence(rle(temp2)$lengths) * temp2 #check for sequential decrease
    
    ind <- which(v1 >= 6) #check for at least 6 increasing
    ind2 <- which(v2 >= 6) #check for at least 6 decreasing
    
    We5 <- c(ind,ind2) #combine indices of ind & ind2
    
    return(We5)
}

ruleone <- function(values,ucl,lcl){
    # values <- data %>% pull(col) %>% na.omit()
    values <- values %>% na.omit()
    len <- length(values) 
    We1 <- c()
    for (i in 1:len) {
        if(!is.na(lcl) == TRUE &&  values[i] < as.numeric(as.character(lcl))){
            We1[i] <- i
        }
        if(!is.na(ucl) == TRUE && values[i] > as.numeric(as.character(ucl))){
            We1[i]  <- i  
        }
    }
    We1 <- as.numeric(We1) %>% na.omit() %>% as.numeric()
    return(We1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include an argument `na.rm`, test it at the beginning of the function and remove the `NA`'s if `na.rm = TRUE`. Something like this:

```
# na.rm defaults to FALSE
rulefour <- function(values, cl, na.rm = FALSE){
  if(na.rm) {
    na <- is.na(values)
    cl <- cl[!na]
    values <- values[!na]
  }
  # rest of code
}

rulefive <- function(values, na.rm = FALSE){
  if(na.rm) {
    na <- is.na(values)
    values <- values[!na]
  }
  # rest of code
}

ruleone <- function(values, ucl, lcl, na.rm = FALSE){
  if(na.rm) {
    na <- is.na(values)
    ucl <- ucl[!na]
    lcl <- lcl[!na]
    values <- values[!na]
  }
  # rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I still get an error message saying "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: @user16394815 Have you done the same for the other functions? `rulefive` and `ruleone` should also start by removing the missing values from `cl, ucl, lcl`.

Comment: @user16394815 See the edit, it now has code for all 3 functions.